# Gnome panel suddenly becomes transparent!

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

My ubuntu is 10.04. The top and bottom gnome-panel suddenly become transparent. However mouse click the position of menu, the Application menu could be shown.

It could be fixed by restarting my x-seesion(logout then login). But it would happen again in several hours.

Does anyone have idea to fix it permanently?

[image]

**Update:**

The compiz is off. However the panel will show after changing the 'Visual Effects' option from 'none' to 'normal'.

**Update2:**
Changing theme also make the panel visible again. But it would be invisible again in minutes.

Comment: Right click your panel and select **None (Use System Theme)** Also are you using compiz?

Comment: @karthick87, I don't set background for that panel. And the compiz is off now. The none option of 'visual effects' is checked. I tried to set it to normal, the panel is shown again! I changed it to none to see what it will happen. Thanks for giving me a hint.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, perhaps in the video driver.  What sort of video card do you have?

Comment: @Marius, I don't think so. I'm using ubuntu 10.04 since it's released. This issue happens in recent days. The pc is  
Dell Optiplex 760.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager "false"
```

Metacity has a compositing manager that doesn't work very well, it shouldn't be activated by default but your problem make me think that it is activated.

After that, restart and see if the problem still occur.

Comment: It looks like work. But I'm not sure whether it's resolved due to removing all packages have word 'compiz'.

Answer (score 0):

To restore gnome panel to default settings.Type the following in terminal

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel && killall gnome-panel &
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Even I have remove 'compiz' package, the problem would be reproduced again.